# how do I create an undordered map containing functions?

Tags: c++, function, struct, unordered-map

I have functions that are working with the following struct:

```
struct stm {
 size_t op; 
 std::string st_out; 
}
```

and I have declared the signature of the unordered map that will save the references:

```
std::unordered_map<uint64_t, std::function<int(stm&, const uint64_t)> instruction_actions;
```

I wrote the functions of which I want to save the reference:

```
bool write(stm&s, const uint64_t item) {
  std::cout << "op: " << s.st_out << std::endl; 
  return true; 
}
```

but how should I add them in the map?

Comment: did you try `instruction_actions[0xCODE]=write`? What error do you see?

Comment: Your function is missing the return statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, your function `write` is missing a return statement.

---

> how should I add them in the map?

There are multiple ways of doing this as shown below:

```
std::unordered_map<uint64_t, std::function<int(stm&, const uint64_t)>> 
                  instruction_actions{{5, write}};
```

Or using `std::map::insert`

```
instruction_actions.insert({5, write});
```

Or using `std::map::operator[]`:

```
instruction_actions[5] = write;
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/onP7T7rqe)

Comment: thank you. Wouldn't it make more sense to pass the function as a reference?

Comment: @awwd We can't store reference into a stl container. Note that  instead of using `{5, write}` in the above example you can also use `{5, &write}` which means you're explicitly taking the address of the function `write`. The reason it works even without using `&` is that functions decays to pointers to function in some contexts. You're welcome.

Comment: `instruction_actions[5] = write;` is also a possiblity to add it to the `map` or overwrite a previously inserted `std::function`.

Comment: @mch Added(pun intended)